Why can't we say “How hard is to earn money”?
Why can't we say “How hard is to earn money”?

It is a question of pleonastic “it”!

Thanks for answer. can we say: how hard is earning money?

Note: “It is hard to earn money”, “How hard it is to earn money!!”

"how hard is earning money?" is grammatical, but user 66974's version is more natural.

For the same reason you cannot say "How far is to London?"

@KadirÇkr   What do you want to say? Do you want to ask a question ❓❓ Make a declarative sentence or an exclamatory sentence ‼️ With "how" you can normally ask a question or an exclamatory sentence.

"How hard is earning money?" is absolutely correct and understandable.  If that works for you, use it.

X is very hard.
Let's make up a question to the word "very":
How hard is X?
Now, instead of "X", we can pick up some word or phrase. For example, if "X" is "the work", then we have:
How hard is the work?
If "X" is "to earn money", then we have:
How hard is to earn money?
Both questions are grammatical because they are subject to the same pattern, but the one with "to earn money" sounds bad to native English speakers because for cases with infinitives, they like to use extraposition:
It is very hard to earn money. — ("to earn money" is an extraposed subject)
How hard is it to earn money?

Yes. A key point for learners is that in English we don't like to use clauses as subjects. We prefer to use extrapositions.


To earn money is hard.

There the infinitival clause "to earn money" is the subject.
If we make "to earn money" the complement of "hard", indicating what is hard:

Is hard to earn money.

there is no subject for "is", so we use empty "It" as a placeholder subject.

It is hard to earn money.

The interrogative form has the above indicative underpinning.
We have seen above that "to earn money" can complement hard, but "is" gets in the way of that complement:

How hard  | is | to earn money.

So we use another empty placeholder "it" :

How hard is it...

and supply the content for empty "it" afterwards:

How hard is it to earn money?


This doesn't actually answer the question though (and to earn money is not the complement of hard!).

You going to tell us about "tough movement"?

It's not a tough construction, it's a control construction :)

1 - it is hard
2 - What is it? (answer: to earn money.)
3 - to earn money is how hard.(declarative)  (Before the wh-movement process)
4 - how hard is to earn money(!)(?) (exclamatory sentence with wh-movement and became the complement of the verb to earn money is.)
5 - [how hard is it] to earn money]]
The phrase to earn money has moved out of the sentence. If this construction is correct… I don't know, I'm no expert.

a) [how hard is it] to earn money]]   ---- b)  [how hard] is it to earn money]]        - ----- My preference: Option A.  However, I am not an expert, both choices can be wrong :)

"To earn money is hard." — an intraposed construction. "It is hard to earn money." — an extraposed construction (via rightward movement). "Money is hard to earn." — a tough construction (via tough movement) or, in CGEL's terminology, a hollow one.

@Loviii Quite correct Unlike my  'control' misfire :)


“How hard is to earn money”

Hard = difficult.

“How hard is to earn money”

is a statement. It is not a question.
"How hard" is not a noun phrase and therefore is not the subject.
"to earn money" is a shortening of "in order to earn money" - this is an adverbial and therefore not the subject.
The sentence requires a subject.
We use a dummy subject: "it" -> "It is hard to earn money”, “How hard it is to earn money"

Hmmmm. Don't think to earn money means 'in order to earn money' here! Compare I go to work to earn money where to earn money actually is an infinitive of purpose  - as opposed to an extraposed subject.

CGEL (p. 921) says we can omit "it + be" in exclamatives: "How kind of you to let me know!". As far as I understand, without omitting, the sentence is "How kind of you it is to let me know!". By analogy with this, is it correct to say "How hard to earn money!" ? Thanks.
